# transparent background-image with a background-color

Tags: css, background, background-image

I'm having a problem with the background property. It should look like this:

http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3425/zbutcmqw_jpg.htm

The triangle has to be transparent and I need the possibility to set the position of this triangle. 
When I use background: url('images/nav.png') no-repeat #1d1d1d; the triangle isn't transparent anymore.

Is there any solution?

Comment: _“The triangle has to be transparent”_ – why? If you want to show something over another (background-)color, then apparently it _can’t_ be “transparent”, because then you would not see it at all. Please be more specific in what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a width and a height to your picture to review it.

**CSS**

```css
 .class,#id{
    background: url('images/nav.png') no-repeat #1d1d1d; 
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute; /* need it to set up the z-index and display your image above the nav menu */
    z-index:100;
    opacity:0.4; /* set up opacity */
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* ie */
    }
```